# Records with Unique (Not Distinct) values in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to have to know which of my users has a UNIQUE OS on their machine

I am not interested in anyone who is not totally unique.  (we are looking for the lone wolves here)  I am not looking for Distinct values.  Just the records that are totally unique.

Here is the SQL

```
CREATE  TABLE `Computers` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `CPU` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `OS` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('386', 'win 3.1');
INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('486', 'Dr Doss');
INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('286', 'win 3.1');
INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('68000', 'Mac OS 7.1');
INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('68030', 'Mac OS 7.1');
INSERT INTO `Computers` (`CPU`, `OS`) VALUES ('Z80', 'CPM');
```

Given this data I should get back only the following rows:

```
ID       OS
2        Dr Doss
6        CPM
```

Can someone help me with the SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING COUNT()`.

```
SELECT ID, OS
FROM Computers
GROUP BY OS
HAVING COUNT(OS) = 1;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause narrows it down to one row per OS and the `HAVING` clause filters out OS 's that have multiple rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbfc2/11

use having example provided above

```
select min(`id`), `os`, count(*) as total
from computers
group by `os`
having `total` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
SELECT * FROM computers
GROUP BY OS
HAVING COUNT(ID) = 1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE TEST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbfc2/14)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM computers
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT OS, COUNT(*) AS OsCount
FROM computers
GROUP BY OS
HAVING OsCount = 1
) Sub1
ON computers.OS = Sub1.OS
```